# Trying to decrease my APK size by removing an unused dependency in gradle

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to remove a library named ly.img.android:photo-editor-sdk version 1.1.0 that was used earlier in my app, but not used anymore, it wasn't giving any errors when compiled. It compiles fine(lint checking disabled), but when I try to run Vuforia camera(completely independet), it runs on one phone(samsung note edge) but not on another(Samsung S8).
This one library increases the APK size by 12Mb, so I'm looking to remove this one, I couldn't understand why it causes issues.

[image]

My app has a single gradle file though, it's been like that since the previous developer who dealt with the app.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
    /*classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'*/
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

    classpath 'com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:1.6.0'

}
}

 configurations {
all {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
}
 }


allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://jitpack.io" }
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com" // specifically this worked
    }
    google()
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
maven {
    url 'https://maven.google.com/'
    name 'Google'
}
}

android {
signingConfigs {
    config {
 //config data
    }
 }
dexOptions {
    jumboMode true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    disable 'MissingTranslation'
}
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.id
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    renderscriptTargetApi 23
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
compileOptions {

    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

}
sourceSets {
    4
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    androidTest.setRoot('tests')
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
}
```

Comment: Just remove `renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true` and `renderscriptTargetApi 23` from `defaultConfig` then clean han rebuild.

Comment: @code4rox Thanks, but the decrease in APK size was less than 1Mb when I did that! Do you know what the libconverter  is?

Answer (score 0):

It can be caused by your resources which are larger from regular resources. In addition, you can go through this link:https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code which will help you to minimize the size of your apk.

Answer (score 0):

had u enabled minify in app.gradle file

I found one blog to reduce the apk size in android. i found it is useful.you can try
[reduce apk size in android](https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-you-can-decrease-application-size-by-60-in-only-5-minutes-47eff3e7874e)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we install a new library in our Gradle then the library package comes in the app and thus our app size increases.
So there must be a new library which you have installed
which is making the size of app increasing.
There are mostly only two ways which increases our app size significantly
1 Adding resource file image or audio etc
2 Installing a new library package

Comment: I understand that, but my apk size has increased even without adding any new gradle dependency, I remember generating an APK a week ago, and it was about 30Mb, now it's about 37!.

Comment: Did you add any new raw files or images or you might have inserted some new data files which are heavy.

Comment: Hi @mohdakbar, that issue is now sorted, it might be due to an addition in a dependency. 
How about this updated question that I posted? Can you help me in this?

Comment: @Mohd Akbar dependency that we add for androidTest will increase the size of apk?